# How to draw wedged double bond in ChemDraw?

Tags: bond, stereochemistry, software

How can I draw a wedged double bond in ChemDraw? When I try to draw BINAP, making the wedged double bond seems impossible. It is however possible to draw a bold double bond.

[image: BINAP]

Comment: I don't remember ever being able to do that. But I also think that that would look weird...

Comment: Note that the shown structural diagrams are not in accordance with the section on hindered biaryls in [_Graphical Representation of Stereochemical Configuration_ (IUPAC Recommendations 2006)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac200678101897).

Answer (score 5):

As [Zhe](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/35555/zhe) pointed out in the comments, bolding *both* bonds looks 'weird', and if you look in textbooks or throughout the chemical literature, BINAP (and related systems) are commonly drawn with only the outer edge bolded (as shown on the left in the image below).

[image]

Although the feature you want isn't directly supported in ChemDraw,  one can get both lines bolded by simply selecting the bond in question, right-clicking, and changing the line width to match the bold width (this gives you the structure on the right hand side of the image below).

That said, just because you **can** do this, doesn't mean you should, it goes against the standard way of drawing these systems, and doesn't add anything in terms of clarity (the first diagram emphasises the stereochemistry perfectly well, the additional bold bond adds nothing).